# ActiveRecord: change and save object state inside model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, models, instance-variables

I have the following code:

```
  def incoming_acceptation(incoming_code)
    if invite_code == incoming_code
      accepted = true
      self.save
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
```

But it does not change and save accepted to true, it remains in the previous state, false.

```
@i.incoming_acceptation(incoming_code) => true
@i.accepted => false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self.accepted = true
```

Comment: I tried that an was not working... then I get confused. Anyway thanks.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that the reason for this is that without the `self.`, `accepted` is interpreted as a local variable within `incoming_acceptation` so the assignment does not change the attribute value.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend:

```
def incoming_acceptation(incoming_code)
  update_attribute(:accepted, true) if invite_code == incoming_code
end
```

`update_attribute` will change and save that attribute. There's also `update_attributes` (notice the `s`) that accepts Hash to change multiple attributes at once:

```
@obj.update_attributes(:accepted => true, :accepted_at => Time.now)
```

Note: `update_attribute` and `update_attributes` both return `true` when the change and save were successful, just like in your example.